"Invalid precision" error when inserting pandas df to SQL Server
I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe into SQL Server but keep getting an error message:

An error occurred: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))]
[parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'CounterpartyMarks', 'dbo')]

The error is coming from this line of code:
df_curr.to_sql('CounterpartyMarks', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={"MTMValue": Numeric(19,2), "FloatPrice": Numeric(19,4)})

When I run the code locally I have no issue inserting into the database. However, this code is compiled into an exe with pyinstaller and distributed to another machine which is where it is failing. The connection is being made to the server successfully but using df.to_sql() seems to fail.
Here is my dataframe data types:
Commodity        object
DealType         object
StartDate        object
Counterparty     object
MTMValue        float64
FloatPrice      float64

I included the modules in hidden imports, but that didn't seem to help:
hiddenimports=['pyodbc', 'sqlalchemy', 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression', 'sqlalchemy.types'],

My module versions:
SQLAlchemy -> 2.0.34
pyodbc -> 5.1.0
pandas -> 2.2.1
pyinstaller -> 6.5.0

DRIVER -> SQL SERVER

Any idea what could be going wrong?
